# Extracting year-month from df. Then grouping to Prepare it for time series analysis. Creating time points starting with/mentioning the first row

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, forecasting

I have a data frame which looks like as below:(i am just creating few rows, in original data there are millions of rows)-

```
raw = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1234, 535, 8494, 843, 7494, 74849, 846, 849, 37, 64],
                     'date': ['2016-01-03','2016-02-06','2016-01-31','2016-03-23','2016-03-23'
                             ,'2016-02-13','2016-01-13','2016-01-11','2016-03-13','2016-04-17']})
raw['date'] = pd.to_datetime(raw['date'])
raw['yearmonth'] = raw['date'].map(lambda x: 100*x.year + x.month)

    date     id  yearmonth
0 2016-01-03   1234     201601
1 2016-02-06    535     201602
2 2016-01-31   8494     201601
3 2016-03-23    843     201603
4 2016-03-23   7494     201603
5 2016-02-13  74849     201602
6 2016-01-13    846     201601
7 2016-01-11    849     201601
8 2016-03-13     37     201603
9 2016-04-17     64     201604
```

Now my first question is, is there any proper way to create the yearmonth column, which will by default give me in the format of year and month, 2016-01,2016-02,2016-03 like that.

The second question is there any other way where I will get the yearmonth column in the format 2016-Jan, 2016-Feb etc.

Now I am grouping by the df on yearmonth column to get the counts.

```
x=raw['yearmonth'].value_counts().sort_index()
Index   yearmonth
201601    4
201602    2
201603    3
201604    1
```

Now I want to build a time series model on these data. So I need the index in monthly format. 
Question 3: How to do it just by mentioning the first time point.
Like in R, we do it like this,

```
ts(df$count,    start   =   c(2016,01), frequency   =   12)
```

And it will automatically start the first row from 2016 jan, then populate the other rows as 2016-feb etc

Question 4: I also needing to be set the new column as index in the dataframe, instead of the old one.
Could somebody please help me on this?